# Части речи

Tags: морфемика, морфология

К какой части речи нужно отнести слово "свежевыпавший"? Какой способ словообразования?

Answer (score 2):

**Свежевыпавший** - прилагательное, образованное сложением основ прилагательного и причастия (СВЕЖ- и ВЫПАВШ-). У этого прилагательного есть синоним - качественное прилагательное НОВЫЙ.

Comment: Согласна с Вами. Причастия  образуются только с помощью суффиксов.

Comment: Да, это прилагательное:
http://jeck.ru/tools/SynonymsDictionary/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9

Comment: Людмила ,прошла по Вашей ссылке и обнаружила новую для себя категорию этой части речи: одушевлённость-неодушевлённость. Как определить эту категорию у прилагательного? Я что-то этого никак понять не могу.(((

Answer (score 1):

Свежевыпавший - это действительное причастие прошедшего времени. Образовано морфологическим способом сложения основ

Comment: причастие образовано от глагола, кажется. Есть глагол свежевыпасть?

Comment: Такого глагола, конечно, нет, но есть "выпасть", а в слове "свежевыпавший" ключевая часть "выпавший" (причастие), ведь слово образовано путем сложения основ

Answer (score 1):

Я бы тоже отнесла это слово к прилагательным несмотря на внешние признаки причастия.